# Loader is not displayed when api is calling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

```js
const HashtagCard = (props) => {
  const { hashtagName, hashtagFollowers, btnText, getHashTags } = props;
  const loader = useLoader();

  const changeFollowingStatus = async (hashtagName) => {
    loader.start();
    try {
      if (btnText === "Follow") {
        await followHashTag(hashtagName).then((response) => {
          if (response) {
            notification.success({
              message: "Followed Hashtag Successfully",
            });
          } else {
            notification.error({
              message: "Unable to follow Hashtag",
            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        await unfollowHashTag(hashtagName).then((response) => {
          if (response) {
            notification.success({
              message: "Unfollowed Hashtag Successfully",
            });
          } else {
            notification.error({
              message: "Unable to Unfollow Hashtag",
            });
          }
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      notification.error({
        message: "Unable to make changes",
      });
    } finally {
      getHashTags();
      loader.stop();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.cardContainer}>
      <div className={styles.cardHeader}>
        <BorderlessTableOutlined />
      </div>
      <div className={styles.cardBody}>
        <span className={styles.tagName}>#{hashtagName}</span>
        <span>
          <UserOutlined /> {hashtagFollowers} followers
        </span>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.cardFooter}>
        <Button
          onClick={() => changeFollowingStatus(hashtagName)}
          type="default"
        >
          {btnText}
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HashtagCard;
```

Loader is not displayed when I click on follow/ unfollow button.
I have used async await method for api call.

Behaviour I want is, if I clicked on that button it should display loader spinner because I have called loader.start() method which sets loader state to true.

In finally block after all api calls are done I called loader.stop() method which sets loader state to false.

Api call is working fine.

Comment: At a glance, this implementation seems OK, and it seems like you have a good understanding of how promises and async/await works. How is `useLoader` defined? Does that work fine, independently of this code? If you're testing locally, are you sure it's not just because the request is being handled instantly and the loader is actually being shown but only for a few milliseconds?

Comment: Yes loader is shown. I have similar code for another functions. It works fine there. But here I think it is not waiting for api call to get finish.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue in jQuery AJAX calls. The problem is when `async` is set to true it fires the API call. And the time it takes to fire the call is smaller than the time it takes to do frontend stuff like displaying loader, etc.

Because of this reason, frontend stuff doesn't work which are supposed to work before the API call is fired.

The solution/hack I found is to introduce a small delay which user will not detect but large portion of time for JS.

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    //API Call Code
}, 100); // 100 milliseconds delay until frontend stuff is done
```

Comment: This should not be needed if the `loader.start()` call is just doing something like `setLoaderVisible(true)` in React, and `loader.stop()` is doing `setLoaderVisible(false)` or something like that.

Comment: Yes It sets the loader state to true. And in finally block it sets it to false. But It is not waiting for api call to get finish

Comment: I would look inside your `followHashTag` function and make sure you are `return`ing a Promise, i.e. `return fetch()` and not just `fetch()`

Comment: export const followHashTag = async (config) => {
  return await apiClient.patch(`hashtags/follow/${config}`, {
    name: config,
  });
};
@BrandonDuffany

Comment: What happens if you `console.log(Date.now())` before and after the `await`? If the timestamps are within a few milliseconds of each other, then `apiClient.patch` might have a bug and is not properly waiting for the response to come back, or you might be passing an invalid argument to it and it's returning immediately

Comment: There is difference of 1639546970798  1639546972639 @BrandonDuffany